# Error when attempting to import JSON into a React component: "You may need an appropriate loader", but the correct loader is already installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm experimenting with Webpack and React, trying out new loaders to see how they work.  Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    hotOnly: true,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
  }
}
```

As you can see, `json-loader` is included in the 'rules' section.

I have `"json-loader": "^0.5.7"` installed under the 'dependencies' section of my package.json, and have run `yarn install` to make sure it's included in my node_modules directory.

I have a simple 'foo.json' file in my /src directory which looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "bazz": {
        "buzz": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
}
```

And I am importing this JSON into a React component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import text from './foo.txt';
import myJson from './foo.json'

const App = () => {
  const buzz = myJson.bazz.buzz;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
      {
        text.split("\n").map((item) => <p>{item}</p> )
      }
      <ul>
      { buzz.map((item) => <li>{item}</li> )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, when I run `yarn run build`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/foo.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = {"f...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = {"f...'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJson (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
    at JsonParser.parse (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/JsonParser.js:16:16)
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:445:32
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:327:12
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /Users/richiethomas/Desktop/Workspace/InvestmentTime/new-react-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
 @ ./src/App.js 4:0-32 7:13-19
 @ ./src/index.js
```

It says I need an appropriate loader to handle this type, but isn't that what `json-loader` is supposed to do?  Do I have a setup or syntax error somewhere?

I have `raw-loader` installed and I'm able to import and render the text from `foo.txt` successfully, so I'm confused why `json-loader` isn't similarly straightforward for me.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I also get this same error when I use `const myJson = require('./foo.json');` instead of `import myJson from './foo.json'`.

Also interestingly, when I *remove* `json-loader` from my Webpack config, both `require` and `import` work as expected.

So, my immediate problem of getting the JSON to load is solved, but I'd still like to know why `json-loader` wasn't working the way I expected it to.

EDIT #2:
From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader), I do see that there is special `require` syntax for inline-importing a JSON file via json-loader:

```
const json = require('json-loader!./file.json');
```

I tried the following, but it also didn't work:

```
const myJson = require('json-loader!./foo.json');
```

Comment: Depending on the version of webpack you're using, you might not need `json-loader` or it could be incompatible with the version of webpack you're using. Make sure to post the relevant versions of the packages you're using.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Webpack v4.19.1 and json-loader v0.5.7.  I understand that loading JSON now simply works with JSON v2.0 and above, and that this loader isn't explicitly needed anymore, but nothing on that docs page I linked to mentions that it's specifically incompatible with later versions of Webpack, and that it might still be needed if a non-".json" file extension is used.  So I'm still hoping to figure out why my config isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message posted

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = {"f...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = {"f...'
```

It looks like the most important part has been truncated a bit.

Note that the first token according to webpack's parser of the posted file is a CommonJS export.

Many webpack loaders are string to string transforms. One after another. The default webpack JSON handling is to convert the file into a CommonJS/ESM as a string. `json-loader` is probably expecting raw JSON, and is instead getting the string form of a CommonJS module of the same.

https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/#json-and-loaders suggests removing the JSON loader unless you have special file endings for JSON files.